# I am unable to use OpenID to login to my Stack Exchange account, how should I get rid of this problem?

Tags: bug, login, stackexchange.com, stack-exchange-openid, google-openid

After deleting my browser cookies I am unable to login via OpenID (which is a Google account).

[image: OpenID problem]

I am also unable to login with my Stack Exchange (SE) account:

[image: Stack Exchange account problem]

The problem only exist while I am trying to login on stackexchange.com.

Login on superuser.com and stackoverflow.com works just fine.

My iOs app also works flawlessly.

Comment: Is the problem only occurring on stackexchange.com? (In other words, are you able to log in on a Q&A site, e.g. here on Meta?)

Comment: @AdamLear Does SE still use OpenID ver 2? Or is it replaced by OAuth?

Comment: Google discontinued the OpenID endpoints a couple years back. We're on OAuth for them.

Comment: @AdamLear looks like I need to update myself! Update: I can login to Superuser.com by my google account, sorry I did not know there is a seperate website domain for each sites like superuser.com, also I am able to login on stackoverflow.com, the problem just exist while I try to login on Stackexchange.com

Comment: @AdamLear Yes the problem only occurs while loggin on stackexchange.com

Comment: That potentially narrows things down a lot, thanks! I'm on bug duty later this week and will investigate further.